# Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): Receive Failure

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Help me please.
After sending post query i have webexception "Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): Receive Failure". help get rid of this error. thanks.

piece of code

```
try
{
string queryContent = string.Format("login={0}&password={1}&mobileDeviceType={2}/",
login, sessionPassword, deviceType);
request = ConnectionHelper.GetHttpWebRequest(loginPageAddress, queryContent);

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())//after this line //occurs exception - "Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): Receive Failure"
{

ConnectionHelper.ParseSessionsIdFromCookie(response);

string location = response.Headers["Location"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
{
string responseUri = Utils.GetUriWithoutQuery(response.ResponseUri.ToString());
string locationUri = Utils.CombineUri(responseUri, location);
result = this.DownloadXml(locationUri);
}
response.Close();
}
}
catch (Exception e)
{
errorCout++;
errorText = e.Message;
}
```

//Methot GetHttpWebRequest

```
    public static HttpWebRequest GetHttpWebRequest(string uri, string queryContent)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);            
        request.Proxy = new WebProxy(uri);
        request.UserAgent = Consts.userAgent;
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        string sessionsId = GetSessionsIdForCookie(uri);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionsId))
            request.Headers.Add(Consts.headerCookieName, sessionsId);

        if (queryContent != string.Empty)
        {
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";
            byte[] SomeBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(queryContent);
            request.ContentLength = SomeBytes.Length;
            using (Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                newStream.Write(SomeBytes, 0, SomeBytes.Length);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            request.Method = "GET";
        }

        return request;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the ConnectionHelper class (or maybe just the GetHttpWebRequest method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    newStream.Write(SomeBytes, 0, SomeBytes.Length);

    //try to add
    newStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to explicitly call the Close() function when using the 'using' keyword?  I thought that the stream was automatically disposed/closed when it went out of scope of the 'using' statement.

Comment: I also think so, but on practise without .Close() it will not send the request.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the server did not send a response body. After fixing the server, the "Receive Failure" vanished.

So you have two options:

1. Don't request a response stream, if you can live without it.
2. Make sure the server sends a response body.

   E.g., instead of

   ```
   self.send_response(200)
   self.wfile.close()
   ```

   the Python server code should be

   ```
   self.send_response(200)
   self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/plain')
   self.end_headers()
   self.wfile.write("Thanks!\n")
   self.wfile.close()
   ```

Answer (score -2):

its **not** Xamarin or .NET's bug. :wink:

your **server side endpoint fails when requesting.** :neutral:

**check your API endpoint** if you own the api or contact support if you are getting API from third party company or service.

why it happens randomly :  :wink: 
because bug is in your inner if or loop blocks and it happens when it goes through this buggy loop or if.

best regards. :smile: