# .net GetResponse Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): ReceiveFailure

Tags: c#, .net

```
    private string PostWebRequest(string postUrl, string paramData)
    {

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(paramData);

        HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(postUrl));
        webReq.Method = "POST";
       webReq.ContentType = "application/json";
        webReq.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream newStream = webReq.GetRequestStream())
        {
            newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        using (WebResponse res = webReq.GetResponse())
        {
            Stream responseStream = res.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
            string str = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            streamReader.Close();
            responseStream.Close();
            return str;
        }
    }
```

When I set contentType a value,it is fail.Like this

> Exception:   at System.Net.WebConnection.HandleError
>   (System.Net.WebExceptionStatus st, System.Exception e, System.String
>   where) [0x00000] in <3acaa45225a54f778710ee6eff26f77f>:0    at
>   System.Net.WebConnection.ReadDone (System.IAsyncResult result)
>   [0x00000] in <3acaa45225a54f778710ee6eff26f77f>:0    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult+<>c.b__27_0
>   (System.Object state) [0x00000] in
>   <3acaa45225a54f778710ee6eff26f77f>:0    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback ()
>   [0x00000] in :0 
>   System.Net.WebConnection.HandleError (System.Net.WebExceptionStatus
>   st, System.Exception e, System.String where) (at
>   <3acaa45225a54f778710ee6eff26f77f>:0) Rethrow as WebException: Error
>   getting response stream (ReadDone2): ReceiveFailure

If I don't set ContentType a value , it  response success.

Comment: convert this `Stream responseStream = res.GetResponseStream();` to a using statement.  may not be the answer but let's clean up this code a bit to start with...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): Receive Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284316/error-getting-response-stream-readdone2-receive-failure)

Comment: newStream.Close(); using does not work

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO

try the following

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Post request 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpObject"></param>
    /// <param name="parameters"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string SendRequest(HttpObject httpObject, IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(httpObject.Url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = httpObject.Method.ToString();

        if (parameters != null)
            foreach (var p in parameters)
            {
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(p.Key, p.Value);
            }


        string result = null;

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(httpObject.Json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        try
        {
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The HttpObject  class

```
 internal class HttpObject 
 {
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public EnumHttpMethod Method { get; set; }
    public string Json { get; set; }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The default content type for ajax is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`.
When you set this to `"application/json";`. The server don't accepts this because you are not sending json you are sending bytes.

When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). As of jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content type header. Note: The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to change the encoding. Note: For cross-domain requests, setting the content type to anything other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request to the server.